# Programmatically invoke rippleJs

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, material-design, ripplejs

**Ripple.JS** ([GitHub](https://github.com/jakiestfu/Ripple.js) | [Demo](http://jakiestfu.github.io/Ripple.js/demo/) | [CDN](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/Ripple.js)) adds a Material style ripple to HTML Elements like this:

```js
$.ripple(".btn", {
  on: 'mousedown', // The event to trigger a ripple effect
  opacity: 0.4,    // The opacity of the ripple
  color: "auto",   // Set the background color. "auto" will use the text color
  duration: 0.7,   // The duration of the ripple
  easing: 'linear' // The CSS3 easing function of the ripple
});
```

#### *Q: Is there a way to programmatically invoke  this?*

**Demo in [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/7dsu3qnd/3/) & Stack Snippets**

```js
$.ripple(".btn", {
  on: 'mousedown', // The event to trigger a ripple effect
  opacity: 0.4,    // The opacity of the ripple
  color: "auto",   // Set the background color. "auto" will use the text color
  duration: 0.7,   // The duration of the ripple
  easing: 'linear' // The CSS3 easing function of the ripple
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootswatch/3.3.7/paper/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Ripple.js/1.2.1/ripple.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Ripple.js/1.2.1/ripple.js"></script>
  

<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" >Click Me</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ripples are created by the local function named `Trigger` inside of the library. Since it's locally declared, we can't execute it directly, but we can add a custom event type in the `options.on` setting.

The only road bump we'll hit is that all ripples **must come from somewhere** (*both intuitively and programatically*), and the trigger function will rely on getting this info from the event coordinates passed in like this [ripple.js#L107](https://github.com/jakiestfu/Ripple.js/blob/v1.2.1/src/ripple.js#L107):

```js
var x = e.pageX - $this.offset().left - $ripple.width() / 2;
var y = e.pageY - $this.offset().top - $ripple.height() / 2;
```

To fake this, we'll have to build and [trigger](https://api.jquery.com/trigger/) our own custom [jQuery Event object](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) from scratch and then stub out the `pageX` and `pageY` properties by finding the center our our new object using [`$.offset`](https://api.jquery.com/offset/), [`.outerWidth()`](https://api.jquery.com/outerwidth/), and [`.outerHeight()`](https://api.jquery.com/outerheight/) like this

```js
$.ripple(".btn", {
  on: 'mousedown ripple', // The event(s) to trigger a ripple effect
});

function InvokeRipple($el) {
  var event = jQuery.Event("ripple");
  event.pageX = $el.offset().left + $el.outerWidth() / 2;
  event.pageY = $el.offset().top + $el.outerHeight() / 2;
  $($el).trigger(event)
}
```

#### Demo in [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/7dsu3qnd/4/) & Stack Snippets

```js
$.ripple(".btn", {
  on: 'mousedown ripple', // The event to trigger a ripple effect
  opacity: 0.4,    // The opacity of the ripple
  color: "auto",   // Set the background color. "auto" will use the text color
  duration: 0.7,   // The duration of the ripple
  easing: 'linear' // The CSS3 easing function of the ripple
});

$("#click").click(function() {
  InvokeRipple($("#info"))
});

function InvokeRipple($el) {
 var event = jQuery.Event("ripple");
  event.pageX = $el.offset().left + $el.outerWidth() / 2;
  event.pageY = $el.offset().top + $el.outerHeight() / 2;
  $($el).trigger(event)
}
```

```css
body {
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootswatch/3.3.7/paper/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Ripple.js/1.2.1/ripple.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Ripple.js/1.2.1/ripple.js"></script>
  

<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" id="click" >Invoke Ripple on other button</button>
<button class="btn btn-info btn-lg" id="info" >More Info</button>
```